# UIButton text color is changing on selection in ios7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, ios7, nsattributedstring

I have a `UIButton` created in IB that I'm setting the title using `NSAttributedString.`

```
NSMutableAttributedString *att = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"skip" attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor redColor]}];
[self.skipB setAttributedTitle:att forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Now normally (< ios7) when I set something only for state `UIControlStateNormal` it will default it for all the states so there is no selected or highlighted state which might change the color of the text when clicking on the button. However, when running in ios7 when you click on the button the text will change color like a light white mask is placed over it. I would like it not to change color. It's very possible that I've missed setting something that should be obvious, but has any one else seen this on ios7?

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help

NSMutableAttributedString *att = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"skip" attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor redColor]}];
[self.skipB setAttributedTitle:att forState:UIControlStateNormal];

and

[self.skipB setAttributedTitle:att forState:UIControlStateSelected];